# Create a subclass of map that can have multiple types for the values

Tags: typescript, class, types, subclass

I have a `Registry` abstract class that extends the Map class. 
There is the code :

```js
abstract class Registry<V> extends Map<string, V> {

}
```

But I want that it can have multiple types for the values **especially a subclass type**, I tried `Map<string, V | W extends V>` but it doesn't work. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: 1. Just for defining value type you could use a simple type alias: `type Registry<V> =  Map<string, V>` 2. Subtypes are already covered by base type, you don't need anything special here: `map.set('foo', subTypeInstance)`

Comment: But my class have multiple fields so I can't do this no ?

Comment: Could you add specific example?